# Can `function`s called in `\tl_map_` and `\seq_map_function`s be defined with more than one argument?

Tags: expl3

In providing an answer to my recent post "Preserving spaces when scanning `tl` variables into a sequence using `\seq_set_split`" Enrico Gregorio defined `\__rn_add:n` to be called by `\tl_map_function`. In experimenting with `\tl_map_` and `\seq_map_function`s it occurred to me that the possibility of defining such functions having more than just one argument would be useful; for example `\__rn_add:nN` might use `#1` for the `tl item` and have `#2` specify to which `_seq` variable to add the item. I assume the `_function` versions of `\tl_map` and `\seq_map` were intended to define processes for general use, while the `_inline` versions provide greatest flexibility but need to be written anew for each `\tl_map_` and `\seq_map_inline`, or am I completely off the mark here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
  \seq_clear:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
  % split at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rn_auxTwo_seq {~} { #1 }
  % the first item is special, pop it out and split it
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_rn_auxTwo_seq \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
  \tl_map_function:NN \l_rn_auxTwo_tl \__rn_add:n
  % now do the other items, reinserting the space before them
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_rn_auxTwo_seq
   {
    \__rn_add:n { ~ }
    \tl_map_function:nN { ##1 } \__rn_add:n
   }
  % print the data
  \textbf{tl~variable:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
  \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_add:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's definitely useful and I think something will appear in the future.

Comment: I conclude it cannot be done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the expandability in a certain point, you can do

```
\cs_set:Npn \__rn_add:n #1 { \rn_macro_with_two_args:nN { #1 } \l_rn_addto_seq }
% ^ this before where you can, and then  v this in an expandable context
\tl_map_function:NN \l_rn_auxii_tl \__rn_add:n
```

But if you don't need expandability you can always do the inline version:

```
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_rn_auxii_seq
 {
  \__rn_add:n { ~ }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { ##1 }
   {
    \rn_macro_with_two_args:nN { ###1 } \l_rn_addto_seq
   }
 }
```

Comment: I experimented with cascading inline versions, except that at the second level I needed four `#` to refer to the argument.